# how to paste powershell script onto the Shell

Tags: 2007, powershell

I am trying to paste powershell script from a website but it doesn't let me right click on powershell console neither    "Crtl + V" is working

i downloaded powershell V.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are surfing the internet and find a PowerShell script that you want to test or eventually save there are several ways to do so. You can copy the contents of the script and save it as a .Ps1 script in notepad or if available download it from the author’s page.

The simplest way to test small PowerShell scripts you find is to use the old copy and paste method as outlined below.

> 1. First copy and paste the contents of the PowerShell script to place it in your clipboard buffer.
> 2. Then from the PowerShell console right mouse click on the PowerShell icon in the upper left hand corner.
> 3. From the context menu click “Edit” and then click “Paste” to execute the script.

Example:

Cat C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Examples\Profile.ps1

Note: Depending on the script in your clipboard buffer you may have to press “Enter” to execute the script as in the example above.

find it here, Hope it helps :)

[enter link description here](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/1/view.asp?id=10958)

Comment: thnx it now working

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why user25328 has a downvote, the right click works well with me too.

**Copy from PowerShell:** Highlight what you want (left click and drag), then right click anywhere on the console to copy the highlighted text.

**Paste to PowerShell:** Simply right click anywhere on the console, it will paste it after the prompt.

**Alternatively:** Alt + Space > E > P

Note: Pasting with line breaks can be annoying, as it executes each line with each new line break.

Answer (score 0):

yup thats becasue you need to change it to be customised as its not available ootb ;)

just follow this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx

or use these:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff678293.aspx

Paste:

Alt+Space+P

Copy:

Alt+Space+Y

hope it helps

Comment: i apply it but no working

Answer (score 0):

Simple way.. Copy the required content.. open the shell > right click > paste :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tweak PowerShell setting to enable right click paste and `ctrl + v` paste

Steps to enable it

1. Select Properties from Title bar

[image: PowerShell Properties from Title bar]

2. Enable `Ctrl+Shift +V` option

[image: Ctlr+V enable PowerShell]

3. Now you can use `Ctrl+v`, `Ctrl+Shift+V` and right click paste

Answer (score -1):

just use The **right click** !!! for both copy and paste